# What is the best way to setup FTP server on Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, ftp, filesystems, cloud

Is it possible to use just Azure Files.
Or is a VM required with FTP server configured and a link to Azure Files.
The data is expected to be 100GB or more.

Comment: Have you looked into using more modern services? FTP is a 50 year old protocol with *several* problems. Can it be solved with Object Storage?

Comment: @vidarlo you are right, In the manuel I can only find information about FTP/SFTP. What modern services could I use?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Manual implies that you're using some product. Which product? Is it possible to work around the limitation, by e.g. writing files to local disk and have a service that uploads them?

Comment: @vidarlo I am trying to upload the data generated from the DAQ (job) device to the Cloud. The device has a build-in support for FTP/SFTP.

Comment: *SFTP*? Is this SSH File Transfer Protocol or some variant of FTP + SSL? If it's *actual* SFTP it's an good and OK protocol, but you're still likely to require a VM or a docker image. Are you deploying *one* device, or many? An alternative would be MQTT if your device supports this...

Comment: Thank you alot for suggestion, I will also take look into MQTT, I think i can also use it. For now it will be STFP (SSH File Transfer Protocol). The goal is to have multiple devices which uploads the generated data to the filesystem through a transfer protocol

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Azure has support for SFTP directly now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support-how-to?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: While [SFTP is now supported for connecting to Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support-how-to), the link you've provided is to a 3rd party offering that deploys FileZilla FTP server on a Windows VM in Azure.

Comment: Be careful here, it's pretty expensive if you turn that feature on.

Answer (score 0):

A VM is required to act as the FTP server.  You can then either mount a managed disk or an Azure Files share to the VM and “share” the files via FTP.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, which option is more cost effective or secure

Comment: @YusufD How long’s a piece of string?  Your best bet is to take a look at the Azure Pricing Calculator and compare the two options.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be that you not use FTP-use SFTP if at all possible because FTP is not secure. Azure Marketplace has a number of offerings and if you type in "SFTP Server," you'll see a bunch of listings.

Look carefully, though, as some of them are companies that have grabbed freeware and made their own offering out of it. Make sure it isn’t based on Filezilla or other freeware. The price is right with freeware, but there is typically subpar support and often security issues. Also look for an option that lets you pay by the hour so you have control over how much you pay and you can add or remove storage as needed.